# equation and sub equation not properly formatted

Tags: equations, amsmath, subequations

I want to write down this equation in latex.

```
\bar\Omega_t=\bar\Sigma_t^{-1}
             =[G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]
```

The code I write down in latex to display this equation is

```
\begin{equation}
\bar\Omega_t=\bar\Sigma_t^{-1}
            =[G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]
 \end{equation}
```

It throws error. Also I want a line by line output meaning  ***\bar\Omega_t=\bar\Sigma_t^{-1}*** equation line no: 1 and ***=[G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]*** equation lin no: 2. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing useing  `align` from `amsmath` package would be better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \bar\Omega_t&=\bar\Sigma_t^{-1}\\
              &=[G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

it is not clear what is your problem. see if any of following example is what you like to obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar\Omega_t = \bar\Sigma_t^{-1}
             = [G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\bar\Omega_t & = \bar\Sigma_t^{-1}   \\
             & = [G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]
\end{split}
 \end{equation}

\begin{align}
\bar\Omega_t & = \bar\Sigma_t^{-1} \\
             & = [G_t\Sigma_{t-1}G_t^T+F_x^TR_t^xF_x]
 \end{align}
 \end{document}
```